# Get Ansible to print lines for include_role(s)

Tags: ansible

I figured this would be trivial, but can't find the answer anywhere.

Let's say I have a playbook.yml that looks like:

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: I'm a block!
    block:
    - name: I'm a role!
      include_role: name=some_role
```

And then I have a main.yml in roles/some_role/tasks that looks like:

```
- name: I'm a task!
  git: repo=https://doesnexist.com/nope.git dest={{ install_path }}
```

What I would expect / like to be printed is:

```
BLOCK [I'm a block!] *********
ROLE [I'm a role!] *********
TASK [some_role : I'm a task!] *********
ok: [MACHINE]
```

Or something like that. Instead, what gets printed is:

```
TASK [some_role : I'm a task!] *********
ok: [MACHINE]
```

So why did I bother putting those names on the block and include_role? Is there any way to get what I want, or at least something close to it? The debug module doesn't do what I want, since it is very poorly formatted.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create a custom callback plugin. I started with the default callback code and modified it:

```
    def v2_playbook_on_task_start(self, task, is_conditional):

        if(task._role is not None and task._role != self._current_role):
            self._current_role = task._role
            self._display.banner("ROLE [" + self._current_role.get_name() + "]", color=C.COLOR_DEBUG)

        self._task_start(task, prefix='TASK')
```

Now the output looks like:

```
ROLE [some_role] *****************************************************

TASK [some_role : I'm a task!] ***************************************
ok: [MACHINE]

TASK [some_role : Some other task!] **********************************
ok: [MACHINE]

ROLE [another_role] **************************************************

TASK [some_role : I'm a task!] ***************************************
ok: [MACHINE]
```

With the role line being bolded. It's a work in progress, but it at least makes it a lot more obvious where roles are being executed. My determination on `block` is that it is impossible to do what I wanted, due to the way the block class is implemented in Ansible.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works. When you said you started with the default callback code, I assume you meant [default.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py). I found that I also needed to add the following line:

`self._current_role = None`


...just before the `super(CallbackModule, self).__init__()` line in the [__init__](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py#L42-L48) function.

Answer (score 0):

[include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) is a task and the name is printed (see below). [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks) is not a task and name is not printed by any [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list).

The play

```
tasks:
  - name: "I'm a block!"
    block:
      - name: "I'm a role!"
        include_role: name=role5
```

gives:

```
PLAY [localhost]
TASK [I'm a role!]
TASK [role5 : I'm a task!]
```

Comment: You're right, it does normally, but I had ``display_skipped_hosts = no`` set, which apparently causes the default callback to skip printing role names. Is there a way to achieve what I want with a custom callback plugin? I've looked over the API but didn't see anything that would let me do so.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither did I. I have no experience with custom callback, sorry. FWIW here is the [Developer Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/#developer-guide).